# WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/104.0.5112/chromedriver unexpectedly exited error using WebDriverManager

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-python

I was trying some scraping using selenium, but when I try to run this code I got this error:

The version I am currently working on.

`Python -- 3.7.13`

`Selenium -- 4.4.3`

`webdrivermanager -- 0.10.0`

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Error:

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-470b559d9ec4> in <module>
      2 from selenium import webdriver
      3 from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
----> 4 driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
      5 import pandas as pd
      6 import time

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in assert_process_still_running(self)
    110             raise WebDriverException(
    111                 'Service %s unexpectedly exited. Status code was: %s'
--> 112                 % (self.path, return_code)
    113             )
    114 

WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/104.0.5112/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6
```

Comment: Version info please of 1) Python 2) Selenium 3) WebDriverManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/104.0.5112/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome)

---

### Details

There seems to some issue with download path of_ChromeDriver v104.0.5112.79_. As per the error message *Selenium* was searching for the ChromeDriver within:

```
/root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/104.0.5112/chromedriver
```

Presumably, following [Index of /104.0.5112.79/](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=104.0.5112.79/) the ideal location should have been:

```
/root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/104.0.5112.79/chromedriver
```

This issue have been raised as [ChromeDriverManager tries to download the latest ChromeDriver from incorrect url](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/885). Feel free to add up your observations to help us debug and address the issue.

Comment: this solution is not working for me

Comment: still same error